# How can i connect my page with Controller

Tags: java, html, spring, thymeleaf

Here i am trying to make a new page with EventController and connect with thymeleaf

```
@Controller
public class EventController {
 @RequestMapping(value = "/pereschet", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String welcome() {
        return "boom";
    }
}
```

here is my html page boom.html

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/web/thymeleaf/layout"
      xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/extras/spring-security"
      layout:decorator="layout">
<head>
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1 >Boombom</h1>


</body>
</html>
```

it is giving me error not found when i am reaching the /timetracking/compensatory/boom
error is Error resolving template "boom", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers

I want to expect the working page, what are the ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default template directory for thymeleaf is src/main/resources/templates. Please make sure you have boom.html placed in this directory as there is no template resolver as per your question. Please take a look at this link I found online for details on custom template resolver. [Spring Boot with Thymeleaf](https://zetcode.com/articles/springbootthymeleafconf/#:%7E:text=Thymeleaf%20template%20files%20are%20located,%2Fmain%2Fresources%2Ftemplates%20.&text=This%20is%20the%20Maven%20build%20file.)